# Display Output is distorted

Tags: c

I have written the following C program. It runs error free but giving distorted display i.e. the output chart is crossing upper value of Time variable, also display not starting at lower limit but at lower+step.

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
  float Time, Distance, step, upper, lower, Accln, Iv;
  Iv = 1.50;
  Accln = 2.0;
  lower = 0;
  upper = 4;
  step = 0.5;
  printf("Distance Time chart for constant Acceleration %3.1f units per sec per sec and initial velocity %3.2f units per sec\n", Accln, Iv);
  Time = lower;
  while(Time<=upper)
  {
    (Distance=Iv*Time+(1.0 / 2.0) * Accln * Time * Time);
    Time = Time + step;
    printf("%3.1f \t\t%3.4f\n",Time, Distance);
  }
}
```

Comment: I hope it is obvious why the display starts at lower+step

Comment: regarding: `main()`   This might have been acceptable back in the '70s, however; today it needs to be: `int main( void )`

Comment: regarding: `Accln = 2.0;`   the variable `Accln` is declared as a `float`, so it should be initialized with a `float`, not a `double`.  Suggest: `Accln = 2.0f;`  Notice the trailing `f`

Comment: regarding: `lower = 0;` and `upper = 4;`  These variables are declared as a `float`, so they should not be initialized with a `int`.  Suggest: `lower = 0.0f;` and `upper = 4.0f;`

Answer (score 3):

You are printing the values after the sum.

Try switching the statements like so:

```
printf("%3.1f \t\t%3.4f\n",Time, Distance);
Time = Time + step;
```

Also `main()` should have a return type:

`int main(){...}`

Comment: No problem, don't forget to [approve the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it's correct.